# External command not running from VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to execute an external program, with some variables when a certain condition is met.  As far as I can tell, the command isn't attempting to run.  I've tried just using `notepad`, or just the `opcmon` command itself, which should generate a usage message.

The only output I get is from the `Echo`, and that looks formatted properly. E.g.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

opcmon.exe "TEST-Goober"=151 -object "C:\Tools"
```

```
' Script Name: FileCount.vbs
' Purpose: This script will send a message to OM with the number
'          of files which exist in a given directory.
' Usage: cscript.exe  FileCount.vbs [oMPolicyName] [pathToFiles]
' [oMPolicyName] is the name of the HPOM Policy
' [pathToFiles] is Local or UNC Path

Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next

Dim lstArgs, policy, path, fso, objDir, objFiles, strCommand, hr

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set lstArgs = WScript.Arguments

If lstArgs.Count = 2 Then
  policy = Trim(lstArgs(0))
  path   = Trim(lstArgs(1))
Else
  WScript.Echo "Usage: cscript.exe filecount.vbs [oMPolicyName] [pathToFiles]" &vbCrLf &"[oMPolicyName] HPOM Policy name" & vbCrLf &"[pathToFiles] Local or UNC Path"
  WScript.Quit(1)
End If

Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FolderExists(path) Then
  Set objDir = fso.GetFolder(path)

  If (IsEmpty(objDir) = True) Then
    WScript.Echo "OBJECT NOT INITIALIZED"
    WScript.Quit(1)
  End If

  Set objFiles = objDir.Files

  strCommand = "opcmon.exe """ & policy & """=" & objFiles.Count & " -object """ & path & """"
  WScript.Echo strCommand
  Call WshShell.Run(strCommand, 1, True)
  WScript.Quit(0)
Else
  WScript.Echo("FOLDER NOT FOUND")
  WScript.Quit(1)
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step to any kind of VBScript debugging: remove `On Error Resume Next`. Or rather, **NEVER** use `On Error Resume Next` in the global scope. ***EVER!***

After removing that statement you'll immediately see what's wrong, because you'll get the following error:

> script.vbs(6, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Variable is undefined: 'WshShell'

The `Option Explicit` statement makes variable declarations mandatory. However, you didn't declare `WshShell`, so the `Set WshShell = ...` statement fails, but because you also have `On Error Resume Next` the error is suppressed and the script continues. When the execution reaches the `Call WshShell.Run(...)` statement, that too fails (because there's no object to call a `Run` method from), but again the error is suppressed. That's why you see the `Echo` output, but not the actual command being executed.

Remove `On Error Resume Next` and add `WshShell` to your `Dim` statement, and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Thank you for the info!  That did it